# startUpdatingLocation + "App registers for location updates" stops working

Tags: ios

I've got an app that requires continuous GPS updates even when in the background.  I've called startUpdatingLocation and have "App registers for location updates" set and I get fixes for about 15 minutes and then the application just stops getting updates.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  On iOS6 in order to save power you stop getting location updates because you are not moving.

locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates fires when this occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to set :

myLocationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

The default value for this property is YES. 
This helped for me, I had your same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the locationManager’s delegate? It was suggested [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/comment-page-1/#comment-18277).

Also: perhaps it is dropping down to a lower accuracy after 15 minute, and giving you notifications of only large changes. Go for a drive, or set distant locations in the simulator, and see if you get updates then.

Comment: Simplest application possible, just NSLog'ing fixes, and I assume with this setup I should get fixes continuously, right?

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];